# What is difference between 'container' and 'generator'?

Tags: python, containers, generator, terminology

My understanding is that *containers* are objects which hold other objects and can be iterated over.

We can also say that `tuple`, `list`, `set`, `dict` are examples of built-in containers.

Please help me understand if the below *iterable* is a container or not:

```
iter(lambda: random.choice(range(4)), 0)
```

The above object holds other objects and can also be iterated over, so it should be a *container*.

Comment: You could argue that that thing "holds other objects", but the objects it arguably holds are *not* the ones produced by iterating over it.

Comment: That's an iterator. All generators are iterators, but not all iterators are generators. What objects do you think that the iterator holds?

Comment: It seems like a semantic argument, but I would say a container is any object that [implements `__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=container#collections.abc.Container), which allows you to ask `if some_thing in some_container:` If you agree with that definition, a lot of things can be containers that don't iterate their members. For example, consider a `Circle` class that "contains" all the points inside it.

Answer (score 2):

This boils down to the difference between code (like in your lambda example) and data. Even though both can be held inside a container in Python (because functions and code blocks are first-class objects), iteration is defined differently for both cases:

- in a container, it means going through the elements one by one
- in a generator, it means coming up with new elements